# Change an image with onclick()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change an image to some other image when i click on the object. the code is stacked in the following order:

```
<li><img><some text></img></li>
<li><img><some text></img></li>
<li><img><some text></img></li>
<li><img><some text></img></li>
<li><img><some text></img></li>
```

What I wish to do is, when I click on the `<li>` i want to change the image to a coloured version of the image, i.e. some other image. Now, I know I can use JQuery/JS to accomplish it. But I don't want a huge amount of JS code to accomplish something so simple.

Can it be done using something simpler? Like pseudo selectors? `.active` class?

I cannot seem to think of it.

Comment: There is no closing </img> tag in HTML like this. You simply need to use <img src="the source of the image" alt=""> or /> for XHTML

Answer (score 25):

To change image onclik with javascript you need to have image with id:

```
<p>
    <img alt="" src="http://www.userinterfaceicons.com/80x80/minimize.png" 
        style="height: 85px; width: 198px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"/>
</p>
```

Then you could call the javascript function when the image is clicked:

```
function changeImage() {
    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "http://www.userinterfaceicons.com/80x80/minimize.png"){
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "http://www.userinterfaceicons.com/80x80/maximize.png";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "http://www.userinterfaceicons.com/80x80/minimize.png";
    }
}
```

This code will set the image to maximize.png if the current img.src is set to minimize.png and vice versa.
For more details visit:
[Change image onclick with javascript link](http://interestingwebs.blogspot.com/2012/09/change-image-onclick-with-javascript.html)

Answer (score 16):

Or maybe 
and that is prob it

```html
<img src="path" onclick="this.src='path'">
```

Answer (score 10):

How about this? It doesn't require so much coding.

```js
$(".plus").click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass("minus")  ; 
})
```

```css
.plus{
    background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ie_Bright/128/plus_add_blue.png");
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.plus.minus{
    background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ie_Bright/128/plus_add_minus.png");
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><div class="plus">CHANGE</div></a>
```

Answer (score 7):

If your images are named you can reference them through the DOM and change the source.

```
document["imgName"].src="../newImgSrc.jpg";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("imgName").src="../newImgSrc.jpg";
```

Answer (score 2):

The most you could do is to trigger a background image change when hovering the LI. If you want something to happen upon clicking an LI and then staying that way, then you'll need to use some JS.

I would name the images starting with bw_ and clr_ and just use JS to swap between them.

example:

```
$("#images").find('img').bind("click", function() {
  var src = $(this).attr("src"), 
      state = (src.indexOf("bw_") === 0) ? 'bw' : 'clr';

  (state === 'bw') ? src = src.replace('bw_','clr_') : src = src.replace('clr_','bw_');  

  $(this).attr("src", src);

});
```

link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/felcom/J2ucD/

Answer (score 2):

Here, when clicking next or previous, the src attribute of an img tag is changed to the next or previous value in an array.

```
<div id="imageGallery">    
    <img id="image" src="http://adamyost.com/images/wasatch_thumb.gif" />
    <div id="previous">Previous</div>    
    <div id="next">Next</div>        
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var images = [
            "http://placehold.it/350x150",
            "http://placehold.it/150x150",
            "http://placehold.it/50x150"    
        ];

        var imageIndex = 0;

        $("#previous").on("click", function(){          
            imageIndex = (imageIndex + images.length -1) % (images.length);    
            $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);
        });

        $("#next").on("click", function(){
            imageIndex = (imageIndex+1) % (images.length);    
            $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);
        });

        $("#image").attr(images[0]);

    });
</script>
```

I was able to implement this by modifying this answer: [jQuery array with next and previous buttons to scroll through entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360092/jquery-array-with-next-and-previous-buttons-to-scroll-through-entries/20360704)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use js, I think, you can use `<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>` instead of `img` and then use css like

```
a {
  background: url('oldImage.png');
}
a:visited {
  background: url('newImage.png');
}
```

EDIT: Nope. Sorry it works only for `:hover`

Comment: But of course you will have to set width and height of anchor explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: url(img1.png) center center no-repeat;
}

.visited {
    background: url(img2.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div href="#" onclick="this.className='visited'">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/gGFgs/)

Answer (score 1):

This script helps to change the image on click the text:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
    var imgpath = $(this).attr('dir');
    $('#image').html('<img src='+imgpath+'>');
    });
    $('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#thumbs').fadeIn(500);
    $('#image').animate({marginTop:'10px'},200);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#hide').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#hide').click(function(){
    $('#thumbs').fadeOut(500,function (){
    $('#image').animate({marginTop:'50px'},200);
    });
    $(this).hide();
    $('#show').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    });
    </script>


<div class="sandiv">
<h1 style="text-align:center;">The  Human  Body  Parts :</h1>
<div id="thumbs">
<div class="sanl">
<ul>
<li dir="5.png">Human-body-organ-diag-1</li>
<li dir="4.png">Human-body-organ-diag-2</li>
<li dir="3.png">Human-body-organ-diag-3</li>
<li dir="2.png">Human-body-organ-diag-4</li>
<li dir="1.png">Human-body-organ-diag-5</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="man">
<div id="image">
<img src="2.png" width="348" height="375"></div>
</div>
<div id="thumbs">
<div class="sanr" >
<ul>
<li dir="5.png">Human-body-organ-diag-6</li>
<li dir="4.png">Human-body-organ-diag-7</li>
<li dir="3.png">Human-body-organ-diag-8</li>
<li dir="2.png">Human-body-organ-diag-9</li>
<li dir="1.png">Human-body-organ-diag-10</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<h2><a style="color:#333;" href="http://www.sanwebcorner.com/">sanwebcorner.com</a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function chkicon(num,allsize) {
    var  flagicon = document.getElementById("flagicon"+num).value;

    if(flagicon=="plus"){
         //alert("P== "+flagicon);

         for (var i = 0; i < allsize; i++) {
            if(document.getElementById("flagicon"+i).value !=""){
               document.getElementById("flagicon"+i).value = "plus";
               document.images["pic"+i].src  = "../images/plus.gif";
            }
          }


         document.images["pic"+num].src = "../images/minus.gif";
         document.getElementById("flagicon"+num).value = "minus";

    }else if(flagicon=="minus"){
         //alert("M== "+flagicon);

          document.images["pic"+num].src  = "../images/plus.gif";    
          document.getElementById("flagicon"+num).value = "plus";

    }else{
          for (var i = 0; i < allsize; i++) {
            if(document.getElementById("flagicon"+i).value !=""){
               document.getElementById("flagicon"+i).value = "plus";
               document.images["pic"+i].src  = "../images/plus.gif";
            }
          }
    }
}
```