# 3 links, 2 div contents, change content on link click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm doing a site for some project and I have this setup

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <img src="Images/image1.png" width="138" height="20" />
    <img src="Images/image2.png" width="138" height="20" />
    <img src="Images/image3.png" width="138" height="20" />
</div>

<div id="leftimage">
    <img src="Images/leftfooter1.png" width="138" height="20" />
</div>

<div id="rightimage">
    <img src="Images/rightfooter1.png" width="138" height="20" />
</div>
```

I want to make it when image 1 is pressed is gets swapped for another image (to indicate the currently selected field) and the images in both divs (leftimage and rightimage) to change. When image2 is clicked same thing but resets other link images to the default state. Also need a default load so it wouldn't be empty if no button was pressed by user.

Edit: Here is an image of what i need basicly, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6X8uGoS_xDwMlo4V3d5VzluUHc/edit?usp=sharing
Because well i'm stupid for JS and cant figure out a thing based on the answers given =/

as you can see from the images there are 3 IMAGES (not text links) with a down state that indicate the selected one. and depending on the selection the left div loads an image and the right div shows text. (also the 1st one should be on by default)

I hope this clears up things a bit and terribly sorry for being a total newbie but like i said i never done JS and getting this thing finished would mean alot to me :)

Comment: I'm not etirely sure what you want to do here. Please be more specific.

Comment: Updated the description so people undrestand better now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could attach onclick events to each of the main images, and call a function with an argument representing which image was clicked:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <img src="Images/image1.png" width="138" height="20" onclick="myfunction(1);" />
    <img src="Images/image2.png" width="138" height="20" onclick="myfunction(2);" />
    <img src="Images/image3.png" width="138" height="20" onclick="myfunction(3);" />
</div>
```

You can then write a js file/function to handle each possible click:

```
var myfunction = function(pictureClicked) {
    // Put logic here, maybe a switch statement?
    switch (pictureClicked) {
        case 1:
            // Pic 1 clicked!
            break;
        case 2:
            //continue from here. 
    }
}
```

Inside this function, you can access the two divs leftimage/rightimage with getElementById.  Once you have the dom element stored in a variable, you can update the innerHTML with the correct image link.  Even better, you can assign id's to both image tags, and change the src attribute directly: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764961/change-an-image-with-onclick).

Comment: Although I posted my answer against yours, I prefer your answer more. I didn't understood the question correctly. My bad. Lucky you. :P

Comment: It is all good :) I had to re-read it a couple of times to see if I could understand!

Comment: Updated the description so people undrestand better now :)

Comment: @Ethernity4ever - I think my solution should still work.  Inside the image tags, add onclick functionality as seen above.  When it is clicked, it will trigger a function, in this case I called it myfunction, but you can call it whatever.  Then you can access the two picture divs to show the images by referencing the div id. Ex:
var div1 = document.getElementById("NameImage");, var div2 = document.getElementById("InfoImage");
Once you get those, you can do something like
div1.innerHTML = "<img src='nameimagelocation'>"; to set the image accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but is this what you wanted?

<kbd>[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/TdT5T/2/)</kbd>

JS:

```
$("#navcontainer img").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("src") == "//dummyimage.com/100") {
        $(this).attr("src", "//dummyimage.com/100/eee");
        $("#navcontainer img").not($(this)).attr("src", "//dummyimage.com/100");
    } else {
        $(this).attr("src", "//dummyimage.com/100");
        $("#navcontainer img").not($(this)).attr("src", "//dummyimage.com/100/eee");
    }
    $("#leftimage img, #rightimage img").attr("src") == "//dummyimage.com/100" ? $("#leftimage img, #rightimage img").attr("src", "//dummyimage.com/100/000/fff") : $("#leftimage img, #rightimage img").attr("src", "//dummyimage.com/100");
});
```

**EDIT:** I updated my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this works but I'm sure someone can possibly shorten it. 
Other thing is that I am assuming that you only have these three links. if your links are generated dynamically then you need a different solution.

```
$(function() {
$('#navcontainer').children().click(function(){
    resetImage();
    $(this).attr('src', 'replacement.jpg');
    $('#leftimage > img').attr('src', 'replacement_left.jpg');
    $('#rightimage > img').attr('src', 'replacement_right.jpg');
});
var resetImage = function(){
    $('#leftimage > img').attr('src', 'http://i58.tinypic.com/5yuwjk.jpg');
    $('#rightimage > img').attr('src', 'http://i58.tinypic.com/5yuwjk.jpg');
    $('.image_one').attr('src', 'http://i57.tinypic.com/5yuw4m.jpg');
    $('.image_two').attr('src', 'http://i57.tinypic.com/5yuw4m.jpg');
    $('.image_three').attr('src', 'http://i57.tinypic.com/5yuw4m.jpg');
};
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/Arllo/wLAfc/

Comment: I just get blank image holders so kinda hard to see if thats it. I posted a update to the question if ti helps :)