# In dreamweaver using css, how to click a button then an image will fade in?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am still new in dreamweaver and still trying to learn new things.
I currently can do an hover image then an image will fade in.
Like below.

```
#home1 {  
    background-image:url(bestseller.jpg);  
    background-size:100%;  
    background-position:center;  
    background-attachment:fixed;  
    margin-top:84px;  
    background-color:#F9C;  
    width:98%;  
    height:500px;  
}  

#home1 {  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;  
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;  
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;  
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;  
          transition: all 0.5s ease;  
}  

#home1:hover{  
    background-image:url(bg.jpg);  
}
```

But the thing is, what should the ":hover" be if I want it to "on click" ?
And what should I type if I wanted to fade an image in (for example home2) by clicking the home1 ?

Note : Without using an URL, so it will still in the same page. And I'm still new so I don't know any relation between javascript and dreamweaver.

Comment: _what should the ":hover" be if I want it to "on click"?_

Guess what youre asking is `:active` state

Comment: nope, :active is only change the image when you continuously clicked the image. But if you let it go, the first image will be back again

Comment: That's DOM manuplation which means you need to write some javascript code. You should check [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764961/change-an-image-with-onclick)

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe I should use the word "button", I want to push a button and the image will change, if I press button 1 then the image should change to image 1, if I press button 2 then the image should change to image 2.

Comment: Well, from i understand from above comment, you dont know javascript at all. Do you?

Comment: Yes, and I already tried this "http://jsfiddle.net/skq64/1/", but it seems like it didn't work in my dreamweaver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74573/discussion-between-batu-zet-and-user3528188).