# JavaScript: onclick not working on image

Tags: html, image, onclick

I am trying to change the image by clicking on it. 
I have written the codes and it's not working.

```
<div class="img fadeIn" >
        <img src="logo.png" height="90px" width="320px" onclick="change()" id="koo" />
    </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function change() {
var mySrc = this.getAttribute('src');
    if( mySrc == 'logo.png' ){
        this.setAttribute('src','logo1.png');
        } else {
        this.setAttribute('src','logo.png');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your javascript console report any errors?

Comment: [This might prove to be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764961/change-an-image-with-onclick/41542141)

Comment: @ZombieChowder It would be better if we make changes and debug the current code instead of changing the whole logic

Comment: @Arex I'm just sending him a link to see how it's done and amend the code to his own. The whole teach a man to fish, give him a fish thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the element as an argument to the function.
I have attached the working code.

```js
function change(t) {
var mySrc = t.getAttribute('src');
    if( mySrc == 'logo.png' ){
        t.setAttribute('src','logo1.png');
        t.setAttribute('alt','logo1');
        } else {
        t.setAttribute('src','logo.png');
        t.setAttribute('alt','logo');
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="img fadeIn" >
        <img src="logo.png" height="90px" width="320px" onclick="change(this)" id="koo" alt="logo"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do tell me if any more help is needed

Comment: @RA'sal Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to do this. Please refer to the code

```
<div class="img fadeIn">
     <img src="logo.png" height="90px" width="320px" onclick="change()" id="koo" />
</div>

function change() {
    var imgTag = event.target;
    var mySrc = imgTag.getAttribute('src');
    if( mySrc == 'logo.png' ){
        imgTag.setAttribute('src','logo1.png');
    } else {
        imgTag.setAttribute('src','logo.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This!

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("koo");
ele.addEventListener('click',function(){
var src = (ele.getAttribute('src') == "logo.png")?"logo1.png":"logo.png";
ele.setAttribute('src',src);
})
```

```html
<div class="img fadeIn" >
      <img src="logo.png" height="90px" width="320px" id="koo" />
</div>
```